# Should I input the after-login pages in robots.txt

Tags: google-app-engine, robots.txt

In our sites, some pages could be accessed only after login...

Is it good to set these after-login pages in robots.txt disallowed ?

Really search the answer from google, but nothing could help...

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would heed the advice from this article:

> To summarize always add the login page to the robots exclusion protocol file, otherwise you will end up:
>
> 1 - sacrificing valuable "search engine crawling time" in your site.
>
> 2 - spending unnecessary bandwidth and server resources.
>
> 3 - potentially even blocking crawlsers from your content.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2009/07/06/seo-tip-beware-of-the-login-pages-add-them-to-robots-exclusion/

Similarly:

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86395/using-robots-txt-to-block-sessionid-urls

Ideally, you'd be able to easily exclude all of those pages via some sort of regex. For example, if all of the urls for these pages started with `/my-account/` then you should be able to do this:

```
disallow: /my-account/*
```